# JUnit load testing thousands of concurrent socket connections to server

Tags: java, sockets, junit, asyncsocket

I have about 100 JUnit tests that simulate a client's socket connection with a server. They look something like this:

```
@Test
public void testProtocolInACertainWay() throws Exception {
    Socket socket = _socketFactory.createSocket(_host, _port);  // SSLSocketFactory

    // Send payload
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.write(/* test-specific payload */);
    outputStream.flush();

    // Receive response
    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());        
    socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int numBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
    buffer = ArrayUtils.subarray(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);

    // Assert test-specific stuff on response
    Assert.assertTrue(buffer[0] == (byte)1);  // for example

    /* At this point, depending on the test, we either repeat similar steps with different payloads or end the test */
}
```

Now, I want to be able to run these tests (or a subset) from a server, 1.5 million at a time. That means that I want to send out 1.5M socket writes concurrently, read them all, and assert on their responses.

Is there a way I can do this without having to rewrite all 100 JUnit tests? (Please say yes, SO :))

Thanks!

Comment: Try http://databene.org/contiperf, http://groboutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Jayan I actually want more like 1.5M and not 100k concurrent tests. will contiperf give me the performance I need, or will I have to switch to Netty or something? Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this from a single test client machine. The maximum number of outbound connections to the same host is limited by the 64k port space.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the response. However, the server has multiple IPs I can connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, turns out what I really wanted to do was use Netty or vert.x. I would have had to rewrite all the tests to use an event queue instead of blocking I/O.